Finding Semantic Duplicates In Dataset
I have one interesting problem to tackle right now:
I have a dataset containing texts of error messages. Every error can be written completely different. Now I have to see, if some rows are semantic duplicates of other rows and group them together.
I have already tried creating an embedding vector for every row and run Agglomerative Clustering on it, it wasn't really perfect. It worked not bad for near-duplicates, but not for semantic duplicates, where the meaning is the same but is written differently.
Do someone has other approaches here? Always open for discussing :)

If your dataset is not to big you could compute cosine similarity between text embeddings and check the higher values to decide of a threshold.
